# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH with Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, cloudflare

I have problem with redirect my website with www to non-www. 
I use Cloudflare. When I redirect traffic https://www.pl.make4u.eu/ to https://pl.make4u.eu/ website I get **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**
I added in Page rules URL/Descriptio, but it doesn't work.

[Page rules, URL/Descriptio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkIjK.png)

In .htaccess I have

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pl.make4u.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Someone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: You need a security certificate that covers the www subdomain.

Comment: How can I get this in Cloudflare? Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

The free edge certificate only provides SSL support up to the third level, i.e. ***.make4u.eu*** in your case, so **.pl.make4u.eu** is not covered in the certificate. You'll need to order a dedicated certificate with custom hostnames from Cloudflare to go beyond that, which is going to cost $10/month.
More information about ordering Dedicated SSL Certificates can be found [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/228009108-Dedicated-SSL-Certificates).

Comment: Could you explain how a mismatched server name would result in the error reported in the question?